# Hide all rows in DataGridView using VB

Tags: vb.net, linq, foreach, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I am trying to filter data in a DataGridView and I need to hide all rows and columns. I try to do this using looping list LINQ & lambda expressions because if I use a foreach it is slow when I try to filter 3000 rows.

The following code executes without errors and works perfectly in c# but doesn't hide the rows in vb:

c# works perfectly

```
dataGridView1.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().ForEach(col => col.Visible = false);
```

vb doesnt works not hide the rows

```
datagrid.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)().ToList().ForEach(Function(obj) obj.Visible = False)
```

when i change Function by Sub send me error

```
datagrid.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)().ToList().ForEach(Sub(obj) obj.Visible = False)
```

I'm looking for the equivalent code C# to vb or the action equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you're not performing the same action between the c# example and the vb.net examples. Columns can be removed because there is no additional column as there is with rows when `Allow User To Add Rows` is set to True. This is the row that appears under your data which allows the user to enter information into another row. Using the code you gave using the **Sub** will work if you set `Allow user to add rows` to  **False** but you can also just check to ensure that you're not trying to set the `EditRow` to hidden, which is what is giving the error you talked about but didn't relay to us.

If you need to keep the `Allow User To Add Rows` set to **True**, then just use:

```
datagrid.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)().ToList().ForEach(Sub(obj) If Not obj.IsNewRow Then obj.Visible = False)
```